# List of system calls with explanation?

Tags: linux, system-calls

Where can I find a list of system calls along with what each call does? I am not a C programmer, I am an admin so at times I find it helpful to run an `strace` on a running process to see what is going on, but there is a lot of stuff I don't understand. I guess I can accept reading the source code, but that is a time consuming endeavor for someone like me who doesn't spend all day programming. Any advice for understanding this facet of GNU/Linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Linux system calls are extensively documented in the [`man-pages` project](https://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/). Start with the list of syscalls, which is [the `syscalls(2)` manpage](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (`man 2 syscalls` on your system). That manpage lists all the syscalls with a very brief summary, and links to the individual manpages documenting each one.

Many system calls are used, with the help of the C library, to provide interfaces specified by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/), so you might find it useful to look them up there (in the “System Interfaces” section).